# null is not an object (evaluating 'this._nativeModule.isBluetoothEnabled') in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, bluetooth, expo

I've recently started to work on react native, I'm trying to integrate react-native-bluetooth-classic to my project.
https://kenjdavidson.com/react-native-bluetooth-classic/api-overview/

However, I'm stuck on this error:

"TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this._nativeModule.isBluetoothEnabled')

This error is located at:
in Untitled (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer"

I have installed the component with

yarn add  react-native-bluetooth-classic --save
and

npx pod-install
The linking seems fine.
I'm copying this example from the library https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic-apps/blob/1cba89aaa1181998dbcab7a9549a88a9bb5071a1/BluetoothClassicExample/App.js#L57. However, is a class component and I would like use function component (so maybe it's that the problem)
Inside my useeffect

```
  useEffect(() => {
  let enabled  = RNBluetoothClassic.isBluetoothEnabled();
```

My RNBluetoothClassic object is NULL and it gave me this error

TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this._nativeModule.isBluetoothEnabled')

from my understanding it should have created it with the import

`import RNBluetoothClassic, { BluetoothEventType } from 'react-native-bluetooth-classic';` 
So I think is a linkage problem or maybe I can't call a class component.

Someone has any idea?
note at the moment I'm trying to test on android

Comment: have you tried instantiating the `RNBluetoothClassic` with the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)?

Comment: You can also try using like this...
  useEffect(() => {
  let enabled  = RNBluetoothClassic?.isBluetoothEnabled();

Comment: @about14sheep in the example they don't do it. I tried and the error is
BluetoothModule is not a constructor

Comment: @HritikSharma didn't work, same error

Comment: I think it could be connected to the package

`@OverRide
protected List getPackages() {
@SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
List packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
// Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
// packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
packages.add(new ReactToolbarPackage());
packages.add(new RNBluetoothClassicPackage());
return packages;
}`

but I think is correct

Comment: Expo has always been a problem for Bluetooth. Some great contributor wrote an expo module import. It's available in the documentation under expo.  Apparently my phone won't copy paste.https://github.com/amitferman/with-rn-bluetooth-classic

Comment: Here is the original issue for expo https://github.com/kenjdavidson/react-native-bluetooth-classic/issues/124

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue, but only in expo app. If I made a react native app with "npx react-native init " the package works for me. Hope this helps!